# Component Diagram

Tags: uml, diagram

I'm building a website for my city. Once the citizen has logged in to the site, he has specific duties. Now I would like to know if in the components diagram I have to insert into the component on the right the web pages that make up the site
this is the diagram
https://ibb.co/iarVAo

Comment: What should that "page component" be at all? Is it one? Just ask yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not. A page is really just something provided by your component (e.g. web application), it’s a way for that component to implement a required function or part thereof. I would suggest modelling the pages that make up the site in a different way, e.g. a navigation map and / or UI wire-frames. I wouldn’t mix these into a Component Model.